# Can I inject a value of a variable with Hilt?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

**For instance...I have this:**

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module

object AlarmInjection {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun proverToday(): Calendar {
        return Calendar.getInstance()
    }

}
```

And in my class, I try to use the variable, which is injected by:

```
    @AndroidEntryPoint
    class AlarmFragment : Fragment() {
    
        @Inject lateinit var today : Calendar

....


}
```

and I get a runtime error when I try to use the today variable.
It says lateinit property is not instantiated.

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property today has not been initialized
```

So, I have to use lateinit to inject anything with hilt, so theorecally is hasnt received value yet. But, the injection itself provides an instance of the Calendar class.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Well theoretically the above could, should work, but since you don't provided much, we can't really tell where the problem lies. Where exactly are you injecting the Calender Property? Did you set all the necessary Annonations correct (e.g: `@AndroidEntryPoint` for activites and fragments, registering a app with `@HiltAndroidApp` etc)? Please provide more code and a use case

Comment: I have other injections in this project, so I know all of the annotations are correct.
I injected this variable in the Fragment( ) class and when I try to use it inside a method, for example onCreateView, it throws the lateinit property today has not been initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Same code is working fine in my case.

Have you annotated `@AndroidEntryPoint` on the activity also which uses this fragment?

As per [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#android-classes) for hilt, activity must also be annotated with `@AndroidEntryPoint` which uses this fragment:

> If you annotate an Android class with @AndroidEntryPoint, then you also must annotate Android classes that depend on it. For example, if you annotate a fragment, then you must also annotate any activities where you use that fragment.